# Is It Possible to Block Redirect Checker Tools from Knowing Where URLs are Redirected?

Tags: php, javascript, html

I want to block URL Redirect Chain Checker tools such as wheregoes(.)com. Is it possible to do it?

For example: wheregoes com/trace/20234194180/ this url can easily tell people where my affiliate link is being redirected. I want to block similar tools from knowing my Cloaked Affiliate Link Redirection.

I am using WordPress site.

Comment: not if you want your redirects to keep working, and if you find a solution it won't work forever either. It's a game of cat and mouse, an arms race. Unless you want your links to lead to somewhere you control where you can gatekeep with a login or a puzzle something only a person can answer before redirecting onwards, then there is no solution to this problem. You could easily hire someone fulltime to work on this if you were a large company and were losing enough money to it. More importantly, _other than coincidence I'm not seeing how this is a WordPress specific question?_